Why does it take IT so long to set up computers for new hires?
In past data science jobs my employer's IT Department has required 3-4 weeks to complete installation of software and set up permissions & data access on my work laptop (for both remote and on-site positions).
However, there is typically a period of weeks or months between accepting a job offer and the first day of work. Wouldn't it be more efficient for IT to use this dead time to set up new employee's computers (using temporary user IDs and passwords) so they can hit the ground running?

That sounds unlucky. I don't think I've ever worked somewhere where it took 3-4 weeks!

because you've worked for companies with crap IT departments.

One job, I walked in the door and on Day One, my computer was waiting for me.  All I had to do is set the password.  The job I have now, I got a loaner on day two and got my permanent computer three weeks later.  My explanation is the shoemaker's kids go barefoot.  We have excellent software support for everything but internal users.

In our company (a global leader in its field with literally billions of users) its because nobody cares.

What do you do in those 3-4 weeks? Surely any kind of manager would scream at their IT department if their new hire cannot work for a month, wouldn't they?

@nvoigt Managers can scream all they want, but sometimes it is a more messy and complex situation.  I was once on a program where it took 3 months.  The reason: IT had run out of resources to allocate, and before I was even brought on had been spending many months fighting with the procurement department to get more.  My joining actually helped give the IT department proof that they were not being overly dramatic that they needed more.

@nvoigt In the past I ran through onboarding training & documentation. With some companies employees have to submit tickets to IT requesting software installation & access to databases. Otherwise you flounder around, figuring out who to ask for help. Some companies didn't offer new hires a simple list of what to do on Day 1 to get connected.

The reasons for a long computer provisioning process is probably very subjective, company-by-company, but here are some common reasons it could take time.
Computer equipment may be ordered or leased on-demand from an outside provider. In this case, the provider's lead time can vary, or be relatively fixed. Either way, the hiring company doesn't want to pay for equipment they're not using, so they'll wait as long as they can to pay for the equipment.
Certain job roles require nonstandard equipment and software, which makes them harder to automate a repeatable build pipeline. Executives, managers, sales, helpdesk, some analysts, these roles may just take a set of hardware/software that's standard to the role and easy to provide, but developers, data science, and other less-standardized roles could need high-powered hardware, special software, exceptions to security policies, etc.
Companies aren't sure whether a new hire will actually make it to onboarding. Many people accept jobs and then ghost the employer, so acquiring and setting up computers, security, and accounts is a waste of the employer's time and money - after repeated ghosting, an employer may change their policy to waiting until the last minute to provision equipment and accounts for new hires.
Additionally, I've worked at companies that put hiring managers in charge of requesting accounts for new employees, and the hiring managers were overworked and forgetful, and would habitually enter employee provision requests late. Usually the turnaround was fairly short so they got away with doing this for some time, but IT was competent and also annoyed with the short timeframes giving by the hiring managers. Nonetheless, this caused some new hires to go a week or so with borrowed computers since their own hadn't arrived yet.

If you do Ruby on Rails work you need an excellent IT person to get your workstation up and running. Getting something not too complicated like a Dart/Flutter workstation takes specific and non-trivial IT knowledge to do. I figured out how to install Flutter, I would not call it hard but it takes specific knowledge to do.

@NeilMeyer, meanwhile, as a C++ developer, I can be up and running with a simple git pull.

Thanks Fredric. Regarding ghosting - even if a new hire ghosts, the employer will still have to fill the position at some point. Why not set up a laptop with software installed and database access connections for whomever fills the role?

@RobertF See my other points; it may take weeks to find and hire another person and leasing an unused laptop for that time is undesirable. Also personnel budgets can be fluid; I worked for an organization that would repurpose open job reqs for other teams if candidates weren't hired in a timely manner. (As in the Answer, this is speculation based on my background in IT for several companies)

Frederic Shope's answer already has some good points, but I just want to add another one: often, IT is not seen as a revenue-generating department, therefore they don't get enough resources, budget, manpower, and training.
The problem that our IT department has is that it takes time to develop automation to get rid of the mundane tasks, but they don't have time to develop that automation because they are so bogged down by all the mundane tasks. Breaking this cycle would require allocating additional resources, budget, and manpower so that there are enough resources to both develop that automation and keep the system running in the meantime. But that is not something that the IT department can do, that needs to be decided at higher levels of management.
The irony is that we pivoted our product portfolio from hardware boxes to cloud-enabled software services right at the beginning of Covid-19. As a result, our R&D, projects, and support engineers spent the Covid-19 "slump" upskilling themselves in DevOps, IaC, Ansible, Terraform, virtualization, Kubernetes, networking, scripting, etc. while at the same time, our IT department was completely saturated with just trying to prevent our infrastructure from falling apart due to the sudden 20x increase in remote working requirements, so they never had the chance to take time for upskilling. As a result, some parts of our company now have better and more modern IT knowledge than IT!
The solution that we came up with is that we will perform a knowledge and skill exchange between the departments. That way, we can help the IT department upskill their people, and at the same time, we can gain their trust and build a working relationship so they can confidently delegate some of their tasks to us in the future.
But I also want to address a specific point you made [bold italic emphasis mine]:

Wouldn't it be more efficient for IT to use this dead time to set up new employee's computers

That implies that IT don't have something better to do during that time. In most organizations, that is not true. Where I work, IT are overworked all the time, so they would never waste any time setting up a laptop for someone who only starts in a couple of months, especially since you never know what might happen in that time.
We've had plenty of cases where someone was supposed to start and then, for various reasons, didn't.

Also, new hardware is generally sourced "just in time" to avoid having valuable depreciating assets losing value in storage, so setting up laptops months in advance will never be allowed by the beancounters.

Speaking for Germany, where new hires sign their written contracts months before their start date:
Incompetence
There is no other explanation. Someone, somewhere, didn't do their job. Didn't forward the information, didn't have a profile of what is needed for the person to do their job, left the task until the last minute or later, etc. Who exactly that is in your company, whether it's the person who designed the process for new hires, or a specific person in that process, is something we cannot say from afar. But there is nothing keeping them from doing so, other than their level of competence. The amount of work is the same, it just gets more and more expensive if you do it after the start date.
The only exception might be very small companies, where you are the first employee of it's kind and they don't actually know what you need. But hiring a second employee for a specific job, there is no reason to not have their starting toolset for them on day one.
In a good company, your manager will have a printout of all your credentials you need (so they aren't floating around digitally in 20 mailboxes to be hacked), and they need to make one single phone call to activate the account that already has all needed priviledges. They will meet you in the morning of your first day, show you the hardware with installed software, give you the credentials, make sure you change all your passwords to something unique to you... that is how you do that. Anything less... is incompetence.
